# How do I Reset Input Fields of Type Number Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input, onclick, reset

I am trying to make a simple calculator web app. All of the actual calculations work but the clear() method at the bottom does not affect the display of my input fields at all. Every resource I find says my function should work but it just won't.

```
<html>
    <body>
    <p>Length: </p><input id="length" type="number"></input>
    <p>Width: </p><input id="width" type="number"></input>
    <p>Height: </p><input id="height" type="number"></input>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="calcMethods">Calculate:</label>
    <select id="calcMethods">
    <option value="volume">Volume</option>
    <option value="area">Area</option>
    <option value="perimeter">Perimeter</option>
    </select>

    <button id="calcVolume" onclick="calcEx()">Go</button>
    <!--This Button Won't Work-->
    <button onclick="clear()">Reset</button>

    <p id="result"></p>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
     //Functions are saved on original file.
     .
     .
     .
      //clears input boxes (WONT WORK!)
      function clear()
      {
        var length = document.getElementById('length');
        var height = document.getElementById('height');
        var width = document.getElementById('width');
    
        length.value = "";
        height.value = "";
        width.value = "";
    
      }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it looks like clear() is a predefined javascript function and I just needed to give the function a different name. Woops!